# Как отправить сообщение пользователю бота в VK

Tags: java, вконтакте, api

Отправляю методом `messages.send` запрос:

```
{
    "userId"=484098711, 
    "chatId"=484098711, 
    "peerId"=484098711, 
    "message"='test message', 
    "domain"='id484098711'
}
```

Возвращается ошибка:

> {"error":{"error_code":100,"error_msg":"One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: you should specify peer_id, user_id, domain, chat_id or user_ids param","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"messages.send"},{"key":"v","value":"5.74"},{"key":"group_id","value":"165342907"}]}}

Я получаю только `user_id` при отправке сообщения пользователем. Где мне брать остальные данные?

Comment: По моему, хватит `user_id` и `message`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/04caeffc98b9c1c010852c40b3b18282a5b89dcc/vk_api__examples/mini_vk_bot.py#L60

Comment: Когда я пишу только user_id и message у меня возвращается такая же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вы делаете POST-запрос с телом в JSON-формате, а VK API принимает GET-запросы с параметрами в query, либо POST-запросы с url-encoded телом (та же query, только в теле запроса).

**GET**:

```
String accessToken = "abcd...";
int user = 1;
String url = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?peer_id=" + user + "&message=test&access_token=" + accessToken + "&v=5.74";

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

**POST**:

```
String accessToken = "abcd..."; 
int user = 1;
String url = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send"
String postBody = "peer_id=" + user + "&message=test&access_token=" + accessToken + "&v=5.74";

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"), postBody)).build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

В примере используется [OkHttp](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.10.0).

Comment: глупый апи у них, ошибка один вид, разные типы разные виды, приходится два раз проверять были ли ошибка и какой тип, еще и документация не указывает как передавать данные что обязательно что нет и не указано что все надо в get((, У телеги все очень и очень просто даже версионирования там нету, там он не нужен)

Comment: @AlexanderBelov да, апи во многом корявый, но он проще некуда.

Comment: ну не знаю, я сравниваю с telegram, все проблемы которые я описал выше комментарием, там отсутствуют

Comment: Теперь еще и абстракция ломается, не получится просто взять и написать класс типа SendMessage  и просто его отправлять

Comment: так привык к апишке телеграмма, что по другому мыслить и не думал или не успел) спасибо

Comment: Взял некоторые идеи, но в основном в либе гавнокод, если точнее, ни code style, ни по паттернам, даже классы по 1000 строк. бойлерплейт, не понятный код. Либо переписать или ни кому не показывать. Надеюсь вы как я любите такую критику. Без обид

Comment: @AlexanderBelov меня не обижает критика в подробной формулировке, от человека, задающего вопросы, подобные тому, на который я здесь отвечал :)

Comment: Поддерживаю, неоправданная сложный код @peter-samokhin советую прислушаться